# Count how many times a letter is contained inside a string

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, string, actionscript, count

The question is pretty self explanatory so
is it possible to count how many times a letter is contained inside a string in as3 
and return the value to some variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is. Have a look at the ActionScript reference for:

[String](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html),
[string.length](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#length), and 
[string.charAt()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#charAt)

Comment: Yes ,that was pretty obvious, i thought about it at first but thiinked if there is some way of doing this without a loop through all the characters in the string.Looks like there isn't , but this worked for me 

var strCount:uint = str.indexOf(String(find.text));
   
for (var k:Number = 0; k < str.length;  k++ )
{ 
if (str.charAt(strCount) == str.charAt(k))
{
numString++;
times.text = numString.toString();
}
}

Answer (score 9):

```
function patternOccurrences(pattern:String, target:String):uint
    {
    return target.match(new RegExp(pattern, "g")).length;
    }
```

Comment: You mean? return target.match(new RegExp(pattern, target)).length;

Comment: no, i mean "g" (as in Global):  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html#RegExp()

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use `split()` on the string and return its length minus one. I find it easier to use than `RegExp` for basic needs.

Example:

```
function getMatchCount(search:String, target:String):int {
    return target.split(search).length - 1;
}

trace( getMatchCount('a', 'aardvark') ); // 3
trace( getMatchCount('ball', 'volleyball baseball basketball football') ); // 4
```

Comment: Weak point of such approach is searching of whitespace character in the beggining or end of a search string will fail to be counted.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked with Actionscript or Flash much - A quick google resulted in this:

```
function getEntranceNumber(mytext:String,myletter:String):Number
    {
        if( myletter.length>1)
        {
            trace("length of a letter should be equal to 1");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            var total:Number = 0;
            var i:Number;
            for( i=0 ; i<mytext.length ; i++ )
            {
                if( mytext[i]==myletter[0] )
                    total++;
            }
            return total;
        }
    }
```

Source : http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=145412

Edit : Here's another link that had some additional information on the same topic :

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=94654 (I believe it even includes a .fla script file)

Answer (score 2):

A solution with RegExp :

```
trace(count("abcdefg", "a"));//1
trace(count("aacdefg", "a"));//2
trace(count("aacdeAg", "a"));//2
trace(count("aacdeaa", "a"));//4
trace(count("aacdeaa", "e"));//1
trace(count("eacdeae", "e"));//3
trace(count("eacdeae", "z"));//0
function count(s : String, letter : String) : int {
    return s.match(new RegExp(letter,"g")).length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer 
this looks like a solution
will try this

Answer (score 1):

Regexps for such a simple task are IMHO overkill. Here's the most straightforward and also very efficient way:

```
    static public function CountSingleLetter( where : String, what : String ):int
    {
        var count:uint = 0;
        for (var k:Number = 0; k < where.length; ++k )
        {
            if (where.charAt(k) == what )
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Put this into some Utils class, or into the String.prototype, ie.

```
String.prototype.RemoveLastChar = function():String
{
    return this.substr(0, this.length - 1);
}
```

calling the prototype version is unfortunately not what you would expect:

```
line = line["RemoveLastChar"]();
```

Replacing the RemoveLastChar with CountSingleLetter left as an exercise for reader :)

Answer (score 1):

This one is 20 times faster, than reg-exp

```
function count(pattern:String, target:String) : uint {
    var count:uint=0;
    var index:int = -1;
    while((index = target.indexOf(pattern, index+1)) >= 0){
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```